# How can I get firebase serve to take over ng serve in an angular Project to whitelist local development?

Tags: angular, firebase, whitelist, firebase-cli

I'm trying to test locally if the verification email I'm sending out to users will redirect users back with an action url.

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions

On a localhost server for project development, I get a 400 error from the firebase server with the error telling me that the "Domain is not whitelisted". So I hope to use firebase serve to somehow get past the whitelisting for my localhost.

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

I'm not sure yet, but I think

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings)
```

works as a cloud function? (If not someone please correct me)

So my main question is, how can I configure my local angular-cli project to use firebase serve for local development in order to get by whitelisting for local development.

e.g.

```
npm start = ng serve (or webpack transpiles typescript to js) and firebase serve (handles transpiled js to get through whitelist)
```

Or is my only choice to actually send my test code to a server somewhere that is whitelisted in order to test this email verification method?